# RegEx to make sure that in an expression all the fields are comma separated and with in braces/brackets

Tags: regex

As I'm pretty new to Regular Expression, I'm looking for a regular expression which will validate whether entire string is comma separated & whether all the  opened brackets/braces are closed.

**Valid Cases:**

```
(abc),(cde),(efg),(1234),[456]

(123),(345),(abcde),123,abc

edf,fgh,123,(abc),(123)
```

**Invalid Cases:**

```
(abc,cde,efg,123),345

[12344,adfc,(bcfgh),(123)

abcdef),123,(1234),(abc),(efgh)

abcdefgh;bcfg;123
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets --> you need to look at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
/^((?:\w+|\(\w+\)|\[\w+\])(,|$))+$/
```

Comment: This question got some really bad specs... Is `abc_123` supposed to pass? This lets it. Should `ABcd` pass? This lets it.

Comment: abc_123 - yes, ABcd -yes

Comment: Thank you @Adam for your time. One thing this Regex neglects is that empty spaced commas. i.e abc, ,1234, ,abc - this is a valid scenario. how will I include this scenario to the above RegEx?

Comment: `/^((?:\w+|\(\w+\)|\[\w+\]|\s+)(,|$))+$/`

Comment: Hi Adam thank you for your support. I have one more query posted regarding regex. Is it possible to have a regex in that pattern?   @Adam                      (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592440/regular-expression-specific-to-a-particular-message-pattern-with-mandatory-eleme)