# Regular Expression specific to a particular message pattern with mandatory elements

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

As I'm pretty new to Regular Expression, I'm looking for a regular expression which will validate whether entire string is separated by `|` and there will be values with `$` followed by an integer.

Valid Values:

```
ABC=$2|CDE=$1|Msg=$4|Ph.No=$3|TIME=$5
ABC=$2|CDE=$1|Msg123=$4|Ph.No=$3|TIME_23=$5    
abc=$2|123=$1|cfg=$4|Ph.No=$3
```

Invalid Values:

```
ABC=$2CDE=$1Msg=$4    
ABC=2|CDE=1|Msg123=$4|Ph.No=$3|TIME_23=$5    
abc$2|123$1|cfg$4|Ph.No=$3    
Msg123=$ |Ph.No=$ |TIME_23=5    
abcdefgh|1234|eghjik    
Msg123=$*|Ph.No=$()|TIME_23=$5    
Msg123=$a|Ph.No=$b|TIME_23=$p
```

Comment: Do we need to parse the string individually and check for it? Is that the only option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it for you:

```
^[\w.]+=\$\d+(?:\|[\w.]+=\$\d+)*$
```

It matches at least one *word character* **or** `.` followed by an `=`, `$` and a digit. Then, optionally, a `|` followed by the first sequence again. This *optional* part can be repeated any number of times.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rW6iN7/3).

**Edit**

Allow multi-digit numbers.

**Edit 2**

If you need to check the range being 0-12 use

```
^[\w.]+=\$(?:\d|1[012])(?:\|[\w.]+=\$(?:\d|1[012]))*$
```

[Here's an example](https://regex101.com/r/rW6iN7/4).

**Edit 3**

As OP needed pure POSIX, here's what *we* ended up with:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(1[012]|[0-9])(\|[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(1[012]|‌​[0-9]))*$
```

No shorthand character classes nor non capturing groups.

Comment: Thank you ClasG!!!...It answers my question but it will miss out if it's a 2 digit no right e.g. Time=$10 or Msg=$12 (need to support 0-12)

Comment: That was based on your examples and the fact that the title contained `=$[0-9]` which also indicated a single digit. Regex updated to allow multiple digits.

Comment: Yes it works...Thank you. Does the same one works in PCRE platform?   "^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(?:\d|1[012])(?:\|[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(?:\d|1[012]))*$"

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. It works in PCRE. In fact if you're using PCRE you could simplify it by using a subroutine: `^([\w.]+=\$(?:1[012]|\d))(?:\|(?1))*$`.

Comment: In my code I need to make sure that it is as per the posix standard, so it doesnot support the escape sequences like the '\' in the regex and \w. I tried the below one but it failed.../^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(?:[0-9]|1[012])(?:\|[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(?:[0-9]|1[012]))*$/

Comment: As far as I can see your conversion works. Otherwise, this should be POSIX compatible: `^[[:alnum:]_.]+=\$(?:[[:digit:]]|1[012])(?:\|[[:alnum:]_‌​.]+=\$(?:[[:digit:]]|1[012‌​]))*$`

Comment: It seems POSIX doesn't support non capturing groups, so try `^[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(1[012]|[0-9])(\|[A-Za-z0-9_.]+=\$(1[012]|[0-9]))*$`